# xml schema meaning question

Tags: xml, xsd, schema

We have a generated XML schema that I am a bit confused on the meaning of the schema (ie, what exactly it is looking for to be valid)

```
<xs:element name="element">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="firstitem_id" type="xs:integer" />
      <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="seconditem_id">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:simpleContent>
            <xs:extension base="xs:integer">
              <xs:attribute name="order" type="xs:integer" />
            </xs:extension>
          </xs:simpleContent>
        </xs:complexType>
      </xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:integer" use="required" />
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

From what I was told, this is really asking for the following:

```
<element>
  <firstitem_id>17</firstitem_id>
  <seconditem_id order="2">34</seconditem_id>
</element>
```

Is this true, and why would this specification show up in this manner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That schema fragment defines the following structural rules for the "element" element:

- It's name is "element"
- It must have an "id" attribute with an integer value (your example does not)
- The child element "firstitem_id"

  - is optional
  - can only be used once
  - it's value must be an integer
  - and it must appear before "seconditem_id" if both elements are in the instance doc
- The child element "seconditem_id"

  - is also optional
  - can appear more than once
  - it's value must be an integer

This is one valid example:

```
<element id="1">
  <firstitem_id>17</firstitem_id>
  <seconditem_id order="2">34</seconditem_id>
</element>
```

This is another:

```
<element id="2">
  <seconditem_id order="2">34</seconditem_id>
</element>
```

This is another:

```
<element id="3">
  <firstitem_id>17</firstitem_id>
</element>
```

And another:

```
<element id="4">
  <firstitem_id>17</firstitem_id>
  <seconditem_id order="2">34</seconditem_id>
  <seconditem_id order="3">35</seconditem_id>
</element>
```

And another:

```
<element id="5">
  <seconditem_id order="2">34</seconditem_id>
  <seconditem_id order="3">35</seconditem_id>
</element>
```

Comment: Thanks, forgetting the id for the base element was just a typo on my part, and I understand the optional requirements, but why would this be generated as the options for "seconditem_id" in this elongated format? I assume there is a much simpler was for these options to be presented.

Comment: It does look as if "seconditem_id" could be expressed as: `<xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="xs:integer" name="seconditem_id">` (untested). As for why it was generated that way, dunno. What tool are you using?

Comment: `xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="xs:integer" name="seconditem_id">` - It won't work.

Answer (score 2):

According to your schema, provided XML isn't valid, because element `element` requires attribute `id` to be set.
Another way to represent you XML is using references in XSD, e.g. equivalent schema:

```
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="element">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="firstitem_id" type="xs:integer" />
                <xs:element ref="seconditem_id" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:integer" use="required" />
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

    <xs:element name="seconditem_id">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:simpleContent>
                <xs:extension base="xs:integer">
                    <xs:attribute name="order" type="xs:integer" />
                </xs:extension>
            </xs:simpleContent>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

</xs:schema>
```

Sample valid XML:

```
<element id="12"/>
```

or

```
<element id="12">
    <firstitem_id>17</firstitem_id>
    <seconditem_id>10</seconditem_id>
    <seconditem_id order="2">34</seconditem_id>
    <seconditem_id>20</seconditem_id>
    <seconditem_id>30</seconditem_id>
</element>
```